# A Circle touching the parabola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$ are points on a parabola $y^2=4ax$ through which a circle is drawn with $AB$ as diameter touching the parabola. Find the $|y_1-y_2|$.

I tried to write the equation of the circle with $AB$ as diameter which is:
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0$$

Now,I need to find a condition to show that this circe touches the parabola. But I don't understand how I can do this. I haven't studied calculus yet.

Comment: Note first that if AB is a diameter of the circle it can only *touch* the parabola at a single point, because no two tangents to the parabola can be parallel. Suppose the two curves touch at A. Construct a line from A parallel to the axis of the parabola, and another line from A though the focus of the parabola. The normal to the tangent (of both curves) at A is a radius of the circle, and it also bisects the angle you have just drawn. This gives you a geometric (non-calculus) point of attack on the problem, though I haven't tried it to see if it is fruitful.

Comment: I found by trial and error, and by writing a small piece of code, that the indicated quantity is equal to $8 a$.  But I don't have proof of why it is so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this question could mean two different things

- Circle is tangent at either A or B, which means it passes through a total of 3 points the reason for that is that if a circle is tangent to a point on either branch of the parabola $[y>0$  and $y<0]$ then it cannot again intersect any point of the parabola located on that branch. I consider this interpretation highly unlikely to be right since there are infinite values of $|y_1 -y_2|$
- Circle is not tangent through A or B but is tangent to a third point C and hence we get to know two things .

  - First: A and B are located on the same branch
  - Second: C is the only point of intersection on the other branch.

  With that we consider parametric points of A, B and C as $(at_{1}^2 , 2at_1), (at_2^2 ,2at_2)$ and $(at_3^2,2at_3)$ respectively.
  $$AC ⊥ BC \\ 
   \frac{2}{t_1 + t_3} . \frac{2}{t_2 + t_3} = -1 \\
  t_3^2 + t_3(t_1 +t_2) + t_1t_2 + 4 = 0 \\$$
  Since there exists only one value of $t_3$,
  $$b^2 -4ac = 0 \\
  (t_1 + t_2)^2 - 4t_1t_2 -16 =0  \\
  (t_1 - t_2)^2 = 4^2 \\
  |t_1 -t_2| = 4 \\
  \therefore  \ \ \ |y_1 - y_2 | = 8a $$